# Ciclo de vida do @ApplicationScoped no ear

Tags: java-ee, cdi

Tenho uma aplicação com vários módulos WEB e um EJB dentro de um EAR conforme imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No módulo EJB criei uma classe anotada com `@ApplicationScoped`, meu objetivo é que esta classe guarde informações que devem ser passadas entre os projetos WEB.
Ocorre que ao adicionar informações na classe no projeto PortalTreinamentosWEB as mesmas não são visíveis no projeto ModuloAluno por exemplo.

Segue código da classe que está anotada com `@ApplicationScope`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceAutenticacao {

private Map<String, Colaborador> mapaTickets = new HashMap<String, Colaborador>();


public ServiceAutenticacao(){
    System.out.println("Objeto service Autenticação criado...........................");
}

public void adicionaColaborador(String ticket, Colaborador colaborador){
    this.mapaTickets.put(ticket, colaborador);
}


public Colaborador getColaborador(String ticket) throws ServiceException{
    if(mapaTickets.containsKey(ticket)){
        return mapaTickets.get(ticket);
    }else{
        throw new ServiceException("Ticket de autenticação inválido: " + ticket);
    }
}
}
```

Segue como que escrevo informações no objeto desta classe no projeto PortalTreinamentosWEB:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PrincipalController {

@Inject private ServiceAutenticacao serviceAutenticacao;

public void redirecionaModuloAluno(){
    //pendura o colaborador com um ticket no Servico de Autenticação entre projetos
    String ticketInterno = UtilService.generateOid();
    this.serviceAutenticacao.adicionaColaborador(ticketInterno , this.colaboradorAutenticado);

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
    String urlModuloAluno = url.substring(0, url.length() - req.getRequestURI().length()) + "/ModuloAluno/autenticacao/autenticacao.jsf?ticketinterno="+ticketInterno;

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {
        context.getExternalContext().redirect(urlModuloAluno);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

E como que tento buscar estas informações no projeto ModuloAluno:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AutenticacaoController {

@Inject private ServiceAutenticacao serviceAutenticacao;

Colaborador colaborador  = serviceAutenticacao.getColaborador(this.ticketInterno);
            System.out.println("Colaborador: " + colaborador.getNome());
            principalController.setColaboradorAutenticado(colaborador);
```

Coloquei um System.out no construtor da classe `ServiceAutenticacao` e percebi que ela está sendo instanciada várias vezes. 
Então minha dúvida é, o objeto anotado com `@ApplicationScope` é o mesmo entre vários projetos de um mesmo EAR ?
Se sim, saberiam me dizer porque não consigo acessar as informações no outro projeto(`ModuloAluno`)

Comment: Qual servidor de aplicação você está usando? É possível testar em outro? O deploy está sendo feito com tudo junto dentro do EAR, certo? A instanciação múltipla não é necessariamente um problema já q algumas instâncias serão proxies, portanto sugiro usar um método com a anotação `@PostConstruct` em vez do construtor para colocar o println. A inicialização do HashMap também poderá ser movida para o `@PostConstruct` (não q isso vá resolver o problema mas fica + correto). Sugiro também testar `@javax.ejb.Singleton` para ver se funciona diferente do `@ApplicationScoped`

Comment: Estou usando o Wildfly 9 como servidor. O deploy está tudo junto dentro de um mesmo EAR. Vou tentar fazer uns ajustes para testar em outro servidor de aplicação. Alterei a inicialização do mapa e o syso para um método `@postconstruct` e observei que a chamada agora ocorre apenas duas vezes. Alterei também para uso do @singleton usando @EJB para buscar o objeto. Observei que quando vou buscar informações no mapa pelo segundo projeto o mesmo está vazio e não tem mais as informações que eu preenchi ateriormente.

Comment: Nos logs de startup ou na interface web de configuração do servidor será que não diz nada? (isto é, será que informa o que está sendo considerado como uma única aplicação e o que é separado — não sei se mudou muito desde o JBoss AS 7 para o Wildfly 9)

Comment: Realmente é muito estranho, vasculhei tudo, na interface web do servidor diz que está tudo empacotado dentro do mesmo EAR. Copiei exatamente o código de outra aplicação que funciona e ocorre o mesmo erro. Só me resta recriar os projetos para fazer um teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei este bug/issue no JBoss: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-129

O que diz lá é que o funcionamento não estava especificado por completo e a decisão de que @ApplicationScoped é instanciado uma vez só por EAR (em vez de um vez por WAR) é relativamente recente, por isso pode não estar funcionando da maneira desejada nos servidores atuais.

Numa lida rápida, vi que apenas no CDI 2.0 é que teremos esse comportamento (1 instância por EAR) garantido :(

Comment: Lí a issue, realmente então temos que usar `@javax.ejb.Singleton` por enquanto que é a única garantia que temos de ter um único em todos os projetos do mesmo EAR. Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Comment: Ah, o @Singleton funcionou? Que bom, não tinha ficado claro no outro comentário e eu já estava pensando em sugerir coisas bem mais diferentes/complicadas, como usar o banco de dados, ou fazer um web service só para isso (argh), ou tentar uma versão beta do CDI 2.0 (ugh).

Comment: Na realdiade não funcionou não, acontece o mesmo caso. Acho que tem algo a ver com o empacotamento, pois os projetos web estão referenciando o ejb na configuração de deployment assembly como um jar. Não sei se isso pode influenciar em algo.

Comment: Para mim, parece correto fazer assim... Provavelmente eu nunca percebi problema porque só usei `@ApplicationScoped` e `@Singleton` para caches ou lazy-loading de configurações. Fica então a ideia de passar o seu Map para o banco de dados... :-/

Comment: Consegui resolver. Eu recriei toda a estrutura dos projetos vazios no eclipse. Depois copiei os arquivos fontes  todos para os projetos novamente e me certifiquei de que as configurações estavam corretas conforme descrito no link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591056/classes-of-referenced-ejb-project-not-found-in-the-referencing-web-project] e funcionou perfeitamente, não alterei uma linha de código sequer. A única explicação que vejo é algum bug no eclipse durante o deploy ou algo do tipo.

Comment: marquei a resposta como correta pois dada a descrição do meu problema sendo uma dúvida sobre o escopo do `@applicationscoped` a mesma é esclarecedora e resolve o problema. Apesar do meu problema ser algo de configuração.

Comment: Interessante. Quer dizer que realmente é possível obter os dois comportamentos dependendo de como o projeto está configurado e/ou como é feito o deploy. Se um dia descobrir qual configuração ou opção de deploy é essa, poste aqui como uma nova resposta, porque pode ser útil para outras pessoas.